# Inserting elements to array in C

Tags: arrays, c

My task is: If we look at any two neighbour values in an array, if the one on the right is two times greater than the one on the left, their average should be inserted between them and the new array consisting of old and new elements should be printed. I have a problem with moving the other elements after average.And using special functions or libraries is not allowed.I am beginner, and I hope you could help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j;
    double a[100], average;

    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((a[i + 1] / a[i]) == 2) {
            for (i = j = 0; i < n; ++i)
                b[j++] = a[i];
            if (a[i + 1] / a[i] == 2) 
                average = (a[i + 1] + a[i]) / 2;
            b[j++] =average;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
        printf("%lf\n", b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always check the return vlaue of scanf, and abort on error.

Comment: You may want to add a \n to the printf format string, to separate the numbers printed.

Comment: Your array `a` can accommodate 100 elements. You should abort if `n > 100`.

Comment: Using string is not allowed. I should increase the size of an array every time the element is inserted and, I just don't know how to move the other elements  forward.

Comment: `a[i+1]=average;` - this part is a problem. I don't know how to move the other elemenets forward and keep the initial value of a[i+1] and just move it to the right.
       `

Comment: I just omitted the restriction on size right now, since my problem is inserting the elements

Comment: Never omit error checking and array out-of-bounds checking in your code, not even in example code. These checks also document your assumptions and design.

Comment: You might consider doing this backwards. Create a large enough output array and populate it from the end of the input array, rather than the start, to prevent having to do any insertions. Finally, simply print the output array in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve your problem is adding `double b[199];`, and copying everything over:

```
for (i = j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  b[j++] = a[i];
  if (...) b[j++] = ...;  /* Append the average to b. */
}
for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
  printf("%lf\n", b[i]);
}
```

If you really want to move the elements forward within `a` itself, then you can do it by adding an inner `for` loop (and an additional loop variable `int k;`) which copies the elements one-by-one:

```
for (k = n++; k > i; --k) {
  a[k] = a[k - 1];
}
```

Comment: I edited the code, but still didn't get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert an element in an array, you must copy the elements with higher index from the last one down.

Also avoid dividing by `a[i]` that can be zero, and properly handle `0,0` that match the criteria for inserting the average, and skip the inserted value to avoid inserting more zeros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;

    double *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * (2 * n - 1));  // allocate the array to the maximum size
    if (a == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%lf", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == a[i - 1] * 2) {
            for (j = n; j > i; j--)
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
            a[i] = (a[i - 1] + a[i]) / 2;
            n++;   // increase number of elements
            i++;   // skip the new value
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%f\n", a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to compile this and for 1 2 3 it will only insert the average between 1 and 2 but not between 2 and 3 so the new array is 1 1.5 2 3

Comment: Why should it insert anything between `2` and `3`? `3` is not twice as large as `2`.

Comment: My mistake, I just forgot that

Comment: And I cannot allocate the array to 2*n-1 since variables are not allowed in declaration of array in standard C.

Comment: @Michael: C99 allows VLAs (variable length arrays), but C++ does not and they have become optional in C11, despite widespread support. I have updated the answer, allocating the array from the heap, which is better to avoid UB if `n` is too large.

Comment: But, I need to use the standard C which is not C99. I know that C99 allows this.

Comment: And, this is actually just the part of the question. I would post the rest of it tomorrow. The original question was to create this array and then get the 1st digit after decimal point of each member and print how many times each of these digits appears. I finished the task, but there are still some problems with my code in cases where there are really small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To insert an element in a specific position you would need to move the rest of the array. However doing it many times is expensive and you may prefer to use an array to store the position at which you want to insert the elements and then insert them all at once.

Alternatively you can create a new array where to copy the original plus the new values.

However there's an easier and faster way, that is adding the new values straight away, while you fill the original array. Here's a program that does that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main() {
    
    int i, n, avg = 0;
    double a[SIZE];
    
    while( puts("Enter the number of elements:") && (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1 || n > SIZE) );
    
    scanf("%lf", &a[0]);
    
    for(i = 1; i < n+avg && i < SIZE-1 && scanf("%lf", &a[i]) == 1; i++) {
        
        if( a[i] == a[i-1] * 2 ) {
            
            a[i+1] = a[i];
            a[i] = (a[i] + a[i-1]) / 2;
            ++avg;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < n+avg; i++) {
        
        printf("%lf\n", a[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i < SIZE` should be `i < SIZE - 1` in case the last element matches the criteria.

Comment: Your approach is clever to avoid teaching the OP how to insert a value inside an array, which seems to be the goal of the assignment :)

Comment: @chqrlie My, my - face palm.  Comment sent to the nether world.

Comment: He meant `a[i]/2` but `a[i]/2` is `a[i-1]` you have to insert the average of the two

Comment: @Davide: *if the one on the right is two times greater than the one on the left* is somewhat confusing, but should translate to `a[i] == 2 * a[i-1]`. Another reading would give `a[i] == 3 * a[i-1]` if the OP meant 200% greater.

Comment: He meant : *one is twice the other*; cause in his program there's this line `(a[i + 1] / a[i]) == 2)`